# Core dump upon invoking newForeignPtr

Tags: haskell, memory-management, garbage-collection, ghc, ffi

The following program :

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as S
import Data.Vector.Storable.Internal
import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import Foreign.Marshal.Alloc

main = do
  let (fp,_,_) = S.unsafeToForeignPtr $ S.fromList [1::Int]
      p = getPtr fp
  copy <- newForeignPtr finalizerFree p -- causes core dump
  print "finished"
```

core dumps with the following error message :

```
"finished"
*** Error in `./test2': free(): invalid size: 0x00007f4dffc06030 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Am I correct in thinking that it is happening because two data values are pointing to the same bit of memory (`p` specifically), which ghc then tries to garbage collect twice? If this is the case is there any way I can make a copy of `p`? If that is not the reason, then  what is causing the problem, and how would I go about fixing it? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "mak[ing] a copy of `p`".  You don't generally need to make copies of Haskell variables, since they are immutable.

Comment: It looks like your data is getting double-freed, once when the vector frees the `ForeignPtr` it gave you (but still retails the ownership of) and once when your `ForeignPtr` frees it using `finalizerFree`. As @jcast mentioned, `newForeignPtr` doesn't copy the underlying data. If you want to do that you need to malloc up some new memory and copy the contents of the first pointer into the second one. Also using `getPtr` is highly unsafe, always use `withForeignPtr`.

Comment: @tibbe Thanks for the explanation. I have been looking over some examples using `newForeignPtr` today and I think I was misusing this facility.